# non-disjoint permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

So, since apparently every calculator I encounter to check my answer does not help with joint cycles, I came humbly to ask if I did this correctly.

$\alpha$ = (1, 3, 2, 5)(6, 4, 7, 3) y $\beta$ = (3, 6, 5, 2)(1, 4, 7, 3)

So, they ask for these: $α$, $\beta$, $α^2$, $α^2$$β$,

Here are my answers:

> Writing it as disjoint cycles:
>
> > $\alpha$ = (1 3 6 4 7 2 5)
> >
> > $\beta$ = (1 4 7 6 5 2 3)
>
> Then operating:
>
> > $\alpha^2$ = (6 1 4 2 3 7 6)
> >
> > $α^2$$β$ = (2 4 6 5 1 3 7)

Hopefully I did this right.

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ look fine, but the rest is strange. How did you calculate $\alpha^2$? (The simple way to do it would be to read off every second element, wrapping around as necessary.)

Comment: Do you compose (multiply) permutations left-to-right [e.g. $(1,2)(1,3)=(1,2,3)$]; or do you compose them right-to-left [e.g. $(1,2)(1,3)=(1,3,2)$]?

Comment: @Théophile:  Many authors compose permutations from left to right.  If the OP is correct about $\alpha$, it means these cycles are composed right to left.  You are correct about the simple way to calculate $\alpha^2$.

Comment: @hardmath I'm puzzled because whatever process was used to get $\alpha$ doesn't seem to have been used to get $\alpha^2$.

Comment: @chrisoname:  The opposite of "disjoint cycles" is not "joint cycles".  I'd be inclined to use "non-disjoint cycles" to describe your compositions.

Comment: I did:

1 -> 3 -> 6
2 -> 5 -> 1
3 -> 6 -> 4
4 -> 7 -> 2
5 -> 1 -> 3
6 -> 4 -> 7

Comment: @Théophile right to left I was taught. like functions.

Comment: I see. That makes sense; you just wrote down the result strangely. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing two different notations. There is a long way to describe a permutation and a short way. The long way list which element maps to which:

$$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Here we have $1$ as a fixed element, while $\sigma(2)=4, \sigma(3)=2$, and $\sigma(4)=3$.

The short way is to write out cycles; the same permutation can be written
$$\sigma = (1)(2 4 3)$$
showing that $1$ is fixed, while we have $2 \to 4 \to 3 \to 2$.

In your answer for $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^2\beta$, you've written out the bottom row of the long notation, which doesn't make sense when read as cycle notation.

Comment: $$\alpha^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
6 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

is this what you mean?

Comment: @chrisoname Yes, exactly. This is $\alpha^2$. The cycle notation would be $(1675342)$.

Comment: Perfect! So I'm in the right track. Thank you very much. Hopefully I can do harder problems now and with better understanding of the difference in notations.